# Finding best curve fit with AIC

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, model-comparison

I have a quite sophisticated problem (for me).
I have written a code that calculates interpolation for a given data set. After that it calculates the Akaike information criterium to check which interpolation suite best.

Looks like that:

```
    polyfit=np.polyfit(x,y,5)  # x,y are data set and 5 is a root of polynomial
    poly1d=np.poly1d(polyfit)    
    print poly1d  #show final polynomial

my=[]
for i in x: 
x_=poly1d(i)
my.append(x_) #calculate list of values 

def AIC(i,j): 
for i in y:
for j in my:
    RSS=(i-j)**2

AIC=36-np.log(RSS) 
print AIC
```

And I don't like this code because if I want to change root of polynomial I have to change the code. I know that I have to use for loop in  the beginning like:

```
for i in xrange(40):
    polyfit=np.polyfit(x,y,i)
```

but I can't figure out how to save all of my polynomials to a list. If I knew that I would use it to calculate def AIC() for any root, and then I could find the best curve fit for my data.
Please help guys, it has been bothering me for 2 weeks already. If there is anything not clear to you, please ask.

Comment: It seems your snippet misses the first line. That being said, what is that you can't store in a list? (I mean which variable) In python you can have a list of any object...

Comment: @CristiánAntuña Actually I know,that I can store in a list but I don't know how.I mean I don't know in this specific problem.How to store in list all of my polynomials which it calculate from  first three lines.And after that how to calculate all values for every polynomial?

Comment: In your for declaration, you can save each polyfit in a list using `poly_list.append(polyfit)` where `poly_list` was a previously declared empty list (i.e. `poly_list = []`). Without your full code I am not sure this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @CristiánAntuña  It might amuse you, but this is entire code ,well except my data and plot graph :)

Comment: Then you should probably spend a little time reviewing Python, half of your lines are wrongly indented. If you get why is that, you will probably be able to fix this problem yourself.